# How extend a jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I tried to extend a jagged array with `Array.AddRange` with no success.
I don't know why it's not working, I've got no exception but the range of my array not change.
Here is the code I use:

```
public World( ushort[][][] worldMatrice)
{
    // OldWith = 864
    ushort OldWidth = (ushort)worldMatrice.GetLength(0);

    // Extend the matrice to (1024) => only the first level [1024][][]            
    worldMatrice.ToList().Add(new ushort[1024- OldWidth][]);
    // NewWidth = 864 , and should be 1024 ...
    ushort NewWidth = worldMatrice.getLenght(0);
}
```

Comment: `Array.AddRange`, isn't that javascript? In .NET, an array is not resizable. You can allocate a new array and copy over the elements but you cannot change the size of an existing array. In any case, you haven't told us what "not working" means, nor have you shown code where you attempt to use it and what results you obtained.

Comment: A jagged array is just a one-dimensional array of arrays. You resize it just like any other one-dimensional array. See marked duplicate for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397694.aspx

Array.AddRange() doesn't change the dimensions of an Array, and Array.Length will always return the max number of elements the array can hold, not the total number of non-null elements inside it.

If you're looking to change the dimensions of the Array, you're likely going to need to transfer the values from the old array to a new Array with dimensions you want.

```
int[] newArray = new int[1024];
Array.Copy(oldArray, newArray, oldArray.Length);
```

To get the number of non-null elements in the array, use something like

```
int count = array.Count(s => s != null);
```

Comment: _"Array.AddRange() doesn't change the dimensions of an Array"_ -- yes, it does. But it's JavaScript, not C#. Also, people who want to resize an array should be told to use `Array.Resize()`, rather than coding the logic explicitly themselves.

Comment: thank you , it's work great

Answer (score 1):

You did not save your output.
Try this:

```
    worldMatrice = worldMatrice.ToList().Add(new ushort[1024- OldWidth][]).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
worldMatrice.ToList()
```

Will create a copy of your array and then you did nothing with that

Comment: So i should => worldMatrice = worldMatrice.toList().Add(.....  ?